# Adding custom Button to AppBarButton in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: image, windows-phone-8

Just getting into Windows Phone 8.1 development.

I quite like it but I am struggling getting accurate development info.

I am working with the Page.BottomAppBar.

I want to use an png image I have created as one of the buttons.

Does this image I created have to be:

1. A certain size
2. A certain format
3. A certain choice of colors i.e. i can use multiple colors and not just black and white

I am looking to create a 'Login' button you see.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the [official Microsoft guidelines for app bars for Windows store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx) and [guidelines for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431806(v=vs.105).aspx). Guidelines cover icons, sizes and formats. It's better to follow them in designing visual style of your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that link. I have seen it before.  This details a lot of info for Metro apps.  I am focusing on Windows Phone 8.1. I know there is a section there, but I just want to know the answers to my basic questions above. Microsoft help I have always personally found unhelpful.  I just want to find direct answers to my questions. I personally find MS tend to  obfuscates my searching for direct info. Hence, why I posted my question here. But thanks for your time :)

Comment: Here is the [guide for icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431806(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Hi Again :). So, 48x48 is the size limit? I cannot use colors?  What about the format i.e. ico, bmp, jpg etc. thanks for that link too :)

Comment: Format is PNG (icons should be transparent), size actually can vary. Framework will resize it very well. Colors are not possible due to internal support of black and white themes (framework will invert icons for you for the black theme).